# Media queries, inline blocks and text-align justify

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I got a problem with aligning elements using inline blocks
It's all normal when i just using technique with `"text-align: justify"`

but when i put all in media query then nothing happens

(elements not aligning width `text-align: justify`)

here is the fiddle how it shoud be

```
ul {
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}

ul:after {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    height: 10px
}

ul > li {
    display: inline-block
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2t6vm/

and there is example width my problem (try to resize result frame)

```
@media only screen and(max-width: 479px) {
     same css
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FYLQq/

Comment: Try putting !important on your media queries.

Comment: @Enijar That isn't an ideal solution - `!important` should be avoided where ever possible, it's bad practice and reduces accessibility and maintainability. Here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/1542891

Comment: Good point, but when it's friday: http://i.imgur.com/vOo8MfG.jpg

Comment: where i should putting !important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check its working in Media queries.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Psy7K/)

@media only screen and (max-width : 479px) {

```
    ul {
        text-align: justify;
        border:solid 1px white;
        width: 100%;
    }

    ul:after {
        content: " ";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        background: #000;
        height: 10px
    }

    ul > li {
        display: inline-block
    }

}
```